# REST Assured POST method with Json File

Tags: json, post, rest-assured

I am new to REST Assured and need help. We have been using Curl to test POST along with --data-binary @file ( this has a json ).

Now how do I test automate using the REST Assured.

Comment: Reading the documentation is a good place for starters. Questions really should not be "how to get started". More on how can I fix what isn't working based on your own code.

Answer (score -1):

RestAssured has neatly documented usage. 
Please visit the github page for RestAssured Usage.

https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage